# Use GetContentResolver in a service while no activity is running

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-context

I need a content resolver to set an event in calendar using a service running in background while i do not have any activity of my app open so i can't get any context or activity object we need to use GetContentresolver kindly guide me what can be done here thanks.

Comment: get application  context

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah I'm new to android kindly tell me how to do that

Comment: A `Service` is a `Context`. Just call `getContentResolver()` directly.

Comment: @MikeM. doesn't work

Comment: Yes, it does. You've posted no code, however, so we can't tell you exactly what you're doing wrong. I would point out, though, that the answer you just accepted is doing that exact thing - `ContentResolver resolver=getContentResolver();` - and the custom `Application` subclass is unnecessary, and not even used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class AppName extends Application
{
    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext()
    {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

In Service class

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
  // TODO: Rename actions, choose action names that describe tasks that this
  // IntentService can perform, e.g. ACTION_FETCH_NEW_ITEMS
  private static final String ACTION_FOO = "com.jvvnl.app.action.FOO";
  private static final String ACTION_BAZ = "com.jvvnl.app.action.BAZ";

  // TODO: Rename parameters
  private static final String EXTRA_PARAM1 = "com.jvvnl.app.extra.PARAM1";
  private static final String EXTRA_PARAM2 = "com.jvvnl.app.extra.PARAM2";

  public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
  }

  /**
   * Starts this service to perform action Foo with the given parameters. If
   * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
   *
   * @see IntentService
   */
  // TODO: Customize helper method
  public static void startActionFoo(Context context, String param1, String param2) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_FOO);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1, param1);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2, param2);
    context.startService(intent);
  }

  /**
   * Starts this service to perform action Baz with the given parameters. If
   * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
   *
   * @see IntentService
   */
  // TODO: Customize helper method
  public static void startActionBaz(Context context, String param1, String param2) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_BAZ);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1, param1);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2, param2);
    context.startService(intent);
  }

  @Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
    ContentResolver resolver=getContentResolver();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Handle action Foo in the provided background thread with the provided
   * parameters.
   */
  private void handleActionFoo(String param1, String param2) {
    // TODO: Handle action Foo
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
  }

  /**
   * Handle action Baz in the provided background thread with the provided
   * parameters.
   */
  private void handleActionBaz(String param1, String param2) {
    // TODO: Handle action Baz
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
  }
```